# history.go(-1) behavior in different browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Does `history.go(-1);` behaves same in all browsers? I am seeing different behavior across various browsers.

My code contains a line similar to `javascript:history.go(-1);`

I have three check boxes in first page. User is allowed to select only two of them. If I select all three and hit submit then in next page, am doing javascript:history.go(-1); using a button saying error message that only two options are allowed. In safari when I come back to first page I see all three check boxes selected, but in firefox only two of them are selected. Chrome, Confirm Form Resubmission message to refresh the page

Comment: it might be good if you can point out the difference you found.

Comment: Click the "edit" link in your question and update it. Questions and answers are "evolving" here.

Comment: Yes I believe that they are different.  But also a solution would be to do a validation on the checkboxes before the submit.  so in the form tag add onSubmit="return validate()" where validate will return false if there are errors and can display them or true if it can go to the next step vs relying on the history.go(-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Browsers can act differently to `histroy.go`.  How you interact with the browser before `history.go` can have different effects when it is called. To make cross-browser javascript is  fairly tricky, but correcting the history issue should be fairly simple. I answered your only question, "Is this true?".  It is likely you want to know how to fix the issue and that is specific to your code.

Comment: it is not a answer, it's better to add it as a comment.

Comment: It answers the only question that was asked `Does history.go(-1); behaves same in all browsers?`.  Planned on updating when he added a question.